# C++ Convert RGB to Hex

Tags: c++, rgb

I need help regarding rgb covertor in the hex code. I am trying to make a function return hex code. I need cString to be hex. For import I use :

```
    dwTitleColor1 // Red
    dwTitleColor2 // Green
    dwTitleColor3 // Blue

const char * CHARACTER::GetTitleColor() const
{
    static char cString[CHARACTER_NAME_MAX_LEN  + 1];
    dwTitleColor1 = 0
    dwTitleColor2 = 0
    dwTitleColor3 = 0

    snprintf(cString, sizeof(cString), "r:%d, g:%d, b:%d.",  dwTitleColor1, dwTitleColor2, dwTitleColor3);
    return cString;
}
```

Comment: So change your format specifier from int to hex in your call to `snprintf()`.

Comment: cString is a string, not hex. If you want hex characters in the string, use %x not %d

Comment: Well that is not right that is a simple test. Is %d becouse is rgb is not hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use C++ tools?

```
std::string CHARACTER::GetTitleColor() const
{
    std::ostringstream buffer;
    buffer.flags(std::ios_base::hex | std::ios_base::left);
    buffer.fill('0');
    buffer <<"r: " <<std::setw(2) <<dwTitleColor1
           <<", g: " <<std::setw(2) <<dwTitleColor2
           <<", b: " <<std::setw(2) <<dwTitleColor3;
    return buffer.str();
}
```

This will write each color as a2-digit hex number. Adapt formatting at will: drop the flags if you want decimal, remove the `setw` and fill if you don't need leading 0.

(And rename that class, you don't want to use all-caps for anything but macros in a C++ program).

**[edit]**
Since it seems to cause a bit of confusion, I want to state that I purposefully changed the return type to be a `std::string`. Because in C++ strings are `std::string`, not `char*`. Its use is very simple:

```
// Assuming myChar is a CHARACTER instance
std::string colorA = myChar.GetTitleColor();    // straightforward
auto colorB = myChar.GetTitleColor();           // better, color gets automatic type from method return type
const auto & colorC = myChar.GetTitleColor();   // if we won't modify it, even better.
```

You can use the returned string however you like. You don't have to free it. It remains valid until it goes out of scope (as opposed to your static char* which gets overwritten if you call `GetTitleColor` on another character).

And if you really have no other choice, you can always do the same thing you were doing with a static: replace the return line with those two:

```
static std::string result = buffer.str();
return result.c_str();
```

It has the exact same caveat your static version had though: calling `GetTitleColor()` again will make the previously returned pointer invalid.

Comment: char.cpp:694: error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' to 'const char*' in return
char.cpp:696: error: cannot convert 'std::string' to 'const char*' in return

Comment: @FrezyFrezy> That's because I made my method return a string. Which it should. In C++, strings should (almost) always be std::string objects, never char *. Unless you have a good reason not to, you should retain the std::string return type, and use it when you call it. I added a note in the answer.

Comment: Updated. Still, you really should drop `char*` in your program instead.

Comment: I don't know if i can becouse this function must return the converted hex from (RGB) and i will use it on chat text in a game.

Comment: @FrezyFrezy> well, yes for this to work, you'd have to update your whole program to take advantage of `std::string`. If it's already big, that may be alot of time. At least think about it when you start your next c++ project :)

Comment: Seams like output is only red: ff green: ff blue: ff so i don't know why is reading only 255

Comment: That's not part of the method so I cannot really help. It prints whatever is in the variables. If it prints ff, your variables have 255 in them.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
snprintf(cString, sizeof(cString), "r:%x, g:%x, b:%x.",  
    dwTitleColor1, dwTitleColor2, dwTitleColor3);
```